# How to select the current element together with parents of a certain class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have something like this:

```
body-viewport
   div-page.active
    div-panel
     div-page
     div-page
     div-page
     div-page.active //start here
```

**Question:**
Is there an easy way in query to select all active-pages if I start from the bottom element?

This would work, but...

```
$('.div-page-active').closest('.body-viewport').find('.div-page-active').doSomething
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: The jQuery docs contain some important information on the difference between closest and parents. Just in case people are wondering why you chose closest over parents http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: What's wrong with the method you propose? What are you trying to avoid? If you have to type that over and over again, wrap it in a jquery plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.div-page-active').closest('.body-viewport').andSelf()
```

**[And Self:](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/)**

> Add the previous set of elements on the stack to the current set.

Comment: I don't think that code will do precisely what the OP wants, but `andSelf` is likely to be part of the solution.

Comment: You're right. I got too type-happy and didn't read the question closely enough. This answers the title but not the actual question.

Comment: I like this! Thanks for pointing my to andSelf, can kick out a big junk of my script now.

Answer (score 1):

So starting from the bottom element, which I'll assume you've received in an event handler and so I'll call `this` (raw element):

If you want all other `.div-page.active` elements **anywhere** under the closest `.body-viewport`, I think your expression is pretty much the best way:

```
$(this).closest(".body-viewport").find(".div-page.active");
```

If you only need `.div-page.active` elements that are *ancestors* of `this` (not siblings or cousins, etc.), then you'll have to write a loop, jQuery doesn't have a "find me all ancestors matching selector X and stop on a match of selector Y". E.g., something like ([live example](http://jsbin.com/igezah/2)):

```
$("#target").click(function() {
  var done = false;
  $(this).parents().filter(function() {
    var $this;

    if (done) {
      return false;
    }

    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.hasClass("body-viewport")) {
      done = true;
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return $this.hasClass("div-page") && $this.hasClass("active");
    }
  }).add(this).css("color", "green");
  display("Matches turned green.");
  return false;
});
```

In that example, when you click the bottommost `.div-page.active`, it turns that one, the `.div-page.active` a couple of levels up, and the `.body-viewport` green. Like this (matches shown in bold below, can't do color on SO), note that I added an unrelated `.div-page.active` and a cousin, to show how they aren't included:

```
body-viewport
 div-page active -- ancestor, should be included
  div-panel
   div-page
   div-page
   div-page
   div-page active -- click me
  div-page active -- cousin, should NOT be included
body-viewport
 div-page active -- unrelated, should NOT be included
```

Comment: this is nice, but to code-heavy for my purpose. One up, cause I also like the way of doing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(this).siblings(".div-page-active").doSomething();
```

Comment: Note his second line in example code. There can be a parent that has that class also.